String algebra - Simplifying expressions of starts-with, ends-with, and contains
I'm trying to wrap my head around what the correct algebraic simplifications would be for the string relations $\text{starts with}$, $\text{ends with}$, and $\text{contains}$. Say I've got two strings $A$ and $B$. Intuition tells me that since $A\text{ starts with }B \Rightarrow A\text{ contains }B$, then:

$A\text{ starts with }B \lor A\text{ contains }B = A\text{ contains }B$
$A\text{ starts with }B \land A\text{ contains }B = A\text{ starts with }B$

But I also want to know how to simplify combinations of $\lnot(A\text{ starts with }B)$ and $\lnot(A\text{ contains }B)$. Following deMorgan's laws would result in:

$\lnot(A\text{ starts with }B) \lor \lnot(A\text{ contains }B) = \lnot(A\text{ starts with }B \land A\text{ contains }B) = \lnot(A\text{ starts with }B)$
$\lnot(A\text{ starts with }B) \land \lnot(A\text{ contains }B) = \lnot(A\text{ starts with }B \lor A\text{ contains }B) = \lnot(A\text{ contains }B)$

But this doesn't make sense to me, because if I know $A$ doesn't contain $B$, then I know that $A$ doesn't start with $B$ - $\lnot(A\text{ contains }B)\Rightarrow\lnot(A\text{ starts with }B)$ - but the converse isn't necessarily true - $\lnot(A\text{ starts with }B)\nRightarrow\lnot(A\text{ contains }B)$ - so shouldn't $\lnot\text{starts with}\lor\lnot\text{contains}$ still be equivalent to $\lnot\text{contains}$? Am I missing something here? I've tried looking for more information on this kind of problem, but to be perfectly honest I'm mostly self-educated on this sort of thing, so I don't even know the right words to describe exactly what I'm trying to solve. For that same reason, I apologize if this is misworded or belongs somewhere else.

$\neg(A\text{ starts with }B)$ indeed does not imply $\neg(A\text{ contains }B)$, but it does imply $\neg(A\text{ starts with }B) \lor \neg(A\text{ contains }B)$ (because $P$ always implies $P \lor Q$), hence the equivalence holds.

But if I said "I want all names that don't start with D or don't contain a D", wouldn't the simpler version of that be "all names that don't contain a D"? If I simplified that to "All names that don't start with D", then names that don't start with it but do contain it would be included.

I think I just realized my own mistake. "names that (don't start with D OR don't contain a D)" would allow "Andy" through, because it doesn't start with a D. But most people (or at least I) would take that to mean "names that don't (start with D or contain a D)" which is actually "names that (don't start with AND don't contain D)," so everything checks out.
